# Math Help - Adjust camera center to keep graphics on screen

Tags: math, geometry

Either my coffee hasn't kicked in yet or I didn't pay enough attention in college, either way I can't wrap my head around the right way to do this calculation.

I have a maze that is made up of zones, the player can only see one zone at a time.  At the moment the camera stays centered on the player, so as they nears the edge of the zone we see every expanding blackness because there is nothing there.  I would like for the camera's center to stay stationary when the player gets close to the adjust of the zone.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
private void ResetRenderView()
{
    // Make sure this control always fills the parent
    this.Size = this.Parent.Size;

    //Calculate and correct CellSize so the screen can always be filled
    int zoneSize = DM.currentDungeon.Settings.ZoneSize;
    float minCellSize = (float)this.Size.Width / (float)zoneSize;
    if (cellSize < minCellSize + .5f) { cellSize = minCellSize + .5f; }

    //Calculate Center Point (usually on Player except when close to the edge)
    Vector2f center = new Vector2f(PlayerLocation.X * cellSize, PlayerLocation.Y * cellSize);
    /**** NEED HELP HERE ****/
    if (center.X < (this.Size.Width / 2) - ((zoneSize * cellSize) / 2)) { center.X = ((zoneSize * cellSize) / 2); }
    renderwindow.SetView(new SFML.Graphics.View(center, new Vector2f(this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height)));
}
```

I believe everything needed to solve this is shown above:

`cellSize` is the pixel size of each cell

`zoneSize` is the number of cells (width and height) in each zone

`this.Size` returns the viewable pixels

`cellSize * zoneSize` will return the total number of pixels (width and height) that the zone uses.

There is currently a single `if` statement for adjusting one part `center.X` and I was planning on doing 3 more.  But I can't get that one to work. I've tried several things. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coffee kicked in.  Here is what I have working:

```
    float totalSize = zoneSize * cellSize;
    if (center.X > totalSize - (this.Size.Width / 2))
    {
        center.X = totalSize - (this.Size.Width / 2);
    }
    if (center.X < this.Size.Width / 2)
    {
        center.X = this.Size.Width / 2;
    }
    if (center.Y > totalSize - (this.Size.Height / 2))
    {
        center.Y = totalSize - (this.Size.Height / 2);
    }
    if (center.Y < this.Size.Height / 2)
    {
        center.Y = this.Size.Height / 2;
    }
```

If anyone can post a better answer (less `if` statements, more elegant, etc...), that isn't just a rewrite of the above code, withing the next few days, I will be happy to mark that as the answer.

Comment: i usually just use a nested Math.max inside a Math.min, but it's basically the same thing